# Is an older APC backup UPS likely to be the source of blown fuses in new lab equipment?

Tags: fuses, ups, equipment

I have new laboratory equipment plugged into an older **APC Back-UPS XS 1000**. It derives all of its power from this backup system, which in turn is plugged into a regular power outlet. The lab equipment has blown a fuse on two separate occasions, once when plugged into the backup battery portion of the APC unit and once when plugged into the surge protector portion of the APC unit.

The APC unit is at least 3, possibly 5+ years old and (according to their website) has an output power capacity of 600 Watts/1000 VA and nominal output voltage of 120V. The lab equipment fuses (there are two fuses operating at all times) are medium blow, 2A and 250V, and made by [Bel](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?KeyWords=507-1278-ND&WT.z_header=search_go) .

The fuses have blown after periods of protracted, heavy use. The lab equipment is less than 6 months old, under warranty and has never gotten wet or been damaged. The equipment's power requirements are 100-250 VAC, 50/60 Hz and 2A.

Is it likely that the older APC unit is the source of these blown fuses? Or is there a potentially problematic mismatch between the power output of the APC and the requirements of my lab equipment?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the product specifications](https://www.apcc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BX1000G&tab=models), this UPS is not a true sine wave output. It uses a stepped approximation to a sine wave. Here is an oscillogram I captured from a similar UPS:

[image: stepped sine oscillogram]

The screen on the left is the waveform, showing that there may be as few as four rough steps per cycle. The screen on the right is the spectrum plot of that waveform, from roughly 60 to 180 Hz, showing the broad-band noise produced by all those sharp vertical edges.

There is a [wide variety](https://superuser.com/questions/912679/when-do-i-need-a-pure-sine-wave-ups/912689#912689) of possible waveforms from this type of UPS. I show this one only as a representative example. You will need to capture your own results if you want a definite answer.

The question then becomes, is a waveform like this an actual problem? Some AC-powered equipment will cope with such ugliness easily. Some won't.

However, I wouldn't expect blown fuses to be a symptom of equipment that can't cope with non-sine power. Also, you will only see ugly output like in the oscillogram when you're running on-battery, since this is not an "[online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply#Online.2Fdouble-conversion)" type UPS. When good quality wall power is present, it is passing the wall power through to your lab equipment unchanged.

If you are hearing this UPS click on and off frequently, it means your wall power is not very good, or the UPS's ability to sense good power is degraded.

I would not hold the age of the UPS against it. With the exception of the batteries, which you should change about every 3 years, UPSes tend not to degrade slowly over time. They either work or not. If your lab equipment is staying powered up through a power outage, I would assume the UPS is working just as well as it did from the factory. The only question in my mind is, how well is that?

For comparison, here's what the output of a true-sine UPS I have here looks like:

[image: true sine UPS oscillogram]

That output is cleaner than the AC line in from the wall!

Comment: Thank you, that was quite helpful. The UPS does not click on/off and all the other lab equipment runs off of the wall power fine. I'll ask the lab instrument manufacturers whether the waveform could be a problem and will look into measuring UPS output.

If the UPS can output a max of 600 Watts and the instrument requires 500 Watts (2A * 250 VAC--- correct calculation?), is this likely to be a problem? I'm wondering if there's a potential power mismatch here that's aggravated by having a new monitor plugged in to the UPS.

Comment: As for your load, you're close enough to your UPS's limits that the turn-on surge might be enough to overload it. If all the lab equipment is powered on when the UPS switches to battery power, this shouldn't be a problem, but it may mean you can't turn it all on at once while the UPS is on-battery, because it may briefly surge over 600 VA. But ask yourself: are these fuses blowing when the UPS is on-battery or not? If not, then I don't see how you can blame an offline type UPS.

Comment: No, the fuses are blowing when the UPS is drawing power from the wall outlet (and is therefore offline). I was hoping the fault would clearly lie with the UPS so I could avoid sending the bulky and pricey new instrument back to the manufacturer but alas, that's looking less likely.

Comment: @Dinah: Your surge protector test confirmed that already, actually. If you want to be doubly-sure, move the lab equipment to a separate *high-quality* surge protector. I mean something like a Tripp-Lite Isobar here, not a $6 big box store piece of junk. If the fuse blows a third time, you've fully exonerated the UPS.

Comment: Good call about running a high quality surge protector trial. That should rule out (or fail to rule out) the UPS, and at the very least will hopefully buy me enough time to finish my experiments! Would you consider [this Belkin surge protector](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-BE112230-08/) to be high quality? My knowledge of such matters is limited.

Comment: No, I wouldn't. I doubt it's actually *bad*, but "high quality?" No. I already gave you my recommendation.